# How do I create a react list component from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

A developer gave me an api specification which is a `List` that can accept an array of objects using the `ListItem` shape described below; this will be transformed into a set of rendered `List.Item` components.

**API**

The `List` component accepts the following props:

- `items` (`ListItem[]`): **Required**. This array should contain one or more JSX elements, or one or more `ListItem` objects (see below for details).
- `searchable` (`string[]`): Optional. Accepts an array of strings which match the names of ListItem properties. If present, a localized freeform search box is rendered above the list, and entry within that field will filter the internal data using the provided keys as a guide.

**Schemas**

---

`ListItem`

`ListItem` is the object schema for an individual item in the list.

```js
{
    // REQUIRED: The main title of the list item.
    title: string,
    // OPTIONAL: A secondary title.
    subtitle: string,
    // OPTIONAL: Additional labeling which appears directly below the title or subtitle label: String,
    // OPTIONAL: If provided, a date will always appear at the top of the list item
    date: Date,
    // OPTIONAL: An array of actions which are appended to the right side of the list item.
    actions: [
        {
            label: string | JSX.Element,
            action: Function
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**My implementation which is not working**

`journalList.jsx`

```js
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React from "react";
import {Components} from "reusable-web-components";

const {
    Icon,
    List
} = Components;

const JournalList = (props) => {
  const {description, title} = props;
  
  const formattedItems = [
    {
        title: title,
        description: description,
        actions: [
            {
                label: <Icon name="edit" />,
                action: () => {}
            },
            {
                label: <Icon name="delete" />,
                action: () => {}
            }
        ]
    }
];
    return(
        <List items={formattedItems} searchable={["title"]} />
    )
}

JournalList.propTypes = {
  "title": PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  "description": PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

JournalList.defaultProps = {
    
};

export default JournalList;
```

---

**Now here is the parent component**

`journal.jsx`

```js
import api from "bees";
import JournalList from './JournalList';
import React from "react";
import store from "store";


class Journal extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            "displayList": true,
            "journalList": null,
            "searchJournalList": []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        store.dispatch(api.getJournals()).then((result) => {
            this.setState(() => ({"journalList": result.body.data}));
        }).
            catch(() => {
                this.setState(() => ({"journalList": []}));
            });
    }

    onEdit = () => {
        // TODO: Update a Journal
    }

    onDelete = () => {
        // TODO: Delete a Journal 
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               
                    <JournalList>
                        {
                            journalList.map((items) => {
                                return{
                                    key={items.title}
                                        title={items.title} 
                                        description={items.description} 
                                }
                            })                            
                        }
                    </JournalList>
               
            </div>            
        ) 
    }   
}


export default Journal;
```

I need to be able to successfully iterate over the data I am getting from my store and create a list of `journal` entries. According to his documentation the output should look like this:

```html
<div>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list__search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input placeholder="Search" id="ListSearch_0.1429790340540955" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list__item">
      <div class="list-item">
        <div class="list-item__contents">
          <div class="list-item-contents">
            <div class="list-item-contents__title">Journal 1</div>
            <div class="list-item-contents__title">Journal 2</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-item__actions">
          <button class="list-item-action"><svg class="icon icon--medium"><use xlink: href="#edit-icon"></use></svg></button>
          <button class="list-item-action"><svg class="icon icon--medium"><use xlink: href="#delete-icon"></use></svg></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The render method of your `Journal` component should be like:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.journalList.map((items) => {
                <JournalList key={items.title}
                             title={items.title} 
                             description={items.description}>
                </JournalList>
                       })                            
            }
        </div>            
    ) 
}
```

And change the state declaration to:

```
this.state = {
        displayList: true,
        journalList: [],
        searchJournalList: []
    }
```

You've reversed the order of the things. The `map()` should wrap the component `<JournalList>`, instead of the `<JournalList>` wrap the `journalList.map()`. Because the `map` will iterate through the `journalList` and create each component.

**EDIT:**

Your JournalList component is *"unuseful"*. It is creating multiple lists, but you only needs one. Change your `<JournalList>` to this:

```js
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React from "react";
import {Components} from "reusable-web-components";
import store from "store"

const {
    Icon,
    List
} = Components;

const JournalList = (props) => {
    state = {
       journalList: []
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        store.dispatch(api.getJournals()).then((result) => {
            var formattedItems = result.body.data.map( data => {
              title: data.title,
              description: data.description,
                 actions: [
                    {
                       label: <Icon name="edit" />,
                       action: () => {}
                    },
                    {
                       label: <Icon name="delete" />,
                       action: () => {}
                    }
                 ] 
              }) // End of the map
            this.setState(() => ({"journalList": formattedItems}));
        }).
            catch(() => {
                this.setState(() => ({"journalList": []}));
            });
    }
    render(){
       return(
          <List items={this.state.journalList} searchable={["title"]} />
       )
    }
}

export default JournalList;
```

Doing this, you `JournalList` component will be useful, and you won't need the `<Journal>` Component.

Comment: I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null`

Comment: Are you sure `journalList.jsx` is the file and not `journal.jsx` because I am still getting the error.

Comment: render() {
        const {displayForm, displayList, journalList} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                
                {journalList.map((items) => {
                    return(                        
                            <JournalList 
                                key={items.title}
                                title={items.title} 
                                description={items.description} 
                            />                       
                        )
                     })                            
           }

Comment: I am still getting the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null`

Comment: Even though I am now seeing everything work. I am getting a separate list for every item.

Comment: @AmenRa Edited. Try it, please

Comment: You are missing a `()` and `return` statement on the .map function and . But that works!!!

Comment: How would I get those `actions` working for the `edit` and `delete` functionality to work?

Comment: I didn't forget the `()` on the map, and the return is a `JSON Object`. I used an [anonymous arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). For the edit and delete actions, you'll need to see how the `<List>` works.